# XMonad Compilation Error using Incorrect Data.Map

Tags: haskell, dictionary, config, cabal, xmonad

So I'm sitting here compiling XMonad for myself because I do not like being provided with version 0.9.1 by my package manager and like 0.9.2. The current problem is that the compilation of XMonad itself succeeds but then I get a weird error when xmonad tries to parse my config file:

```
xmonad.hs:254:15:
    Couldn't match expected type `containers-0.3.0.0:Data.Map.Map
                                    (ButtonMask, KeySym) (X ())'
           against inferred type `M.Map (KeyMask, KeySym) (X ())'
    In the `keys' field of a record
    In the first argument of `xmobar', namely
        `myBaseConfig
           {modMask = myModMask,
            workspaces = withScreens nScreens myWorkspaces,
            layoutHook = myLayoutHook nScreens, manageHook = myManageHook,
            borderWidth = myBorderWidth,
            normalBorderColor = myNormalBorderColor,
            focusedBorderColor = myFocusedBorderColor, keys = myKeys,
            mouseBindings = myMouseBindings, logHook = myLogHook}'
    In the second argument of `(=<<)', namely
        `xmobar
           (myBaseConfig
              {modMask = myModMask,
               workspaces = withScreens nScreens myWorkspaces,
               layoutHook = myLayoutHook nScreens, manageHook = myManageHook,
               borderWidth = myBorderWidth,
               normalBorderColor = myNormalBorderColor,
               focusedBorderColor = myFocusedBorderColor, keys = myKeys,
               mouseBindings = myMouseBindings, logHook = myLogHook})'
```

I was able to trace the cause of the problem down and it is displayed in this ghci session below:

```
GHCi, version 6.12.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
$ :m xmonad
syntax:  :module [+/-] [*]M1 ... [*]Mn
$ :m XMonad
$ :t XConfig
XConfig
  :: String
     -> String
     -> String
     -> l Window
     -> ManageHook
     -> (Event -> X Data.Monoid.All)
     -> [String]
     -> KeyMask
     -> KeyMask
     -> (XConfig Layout
         -> containers-0.3.0.0:Data.Map.Map (ButtonMask, KeySym) (X ()))
     -> (XConfig Layout
         -> containers-0.3.0.0:Data.Map.Map
              (ButtonMask, Button) (Window -> X ()))
     -> Dimension
     -> X ()
     -> X ()
     -> Bool
     -> XConfig l
$ 
Leaving GHCi.
```

The problem seems to be this line:

```
         -> containers-0.3.0.0:Data.Map.Map (ButtonMask, KeySym) (X ()))
```

I would have thought that it might have said:

```
         -> M.Map (ButtonMask, KeySym) (X ()))
```

I am just wondering if I diagnosed the problem correctly and if so, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Looks like ghc is attempting to try to compile your code to two different versions of the `container` package: The same type from two different versions is a different type, as far as GHC can see. Have a look at `ghc-pkg list containers`. That said, such problems are often best solved interactively, do come around #haskell (or possibly #xmonad) on freenode if things get hairy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you might have two versions of `containers` installed. You can confirm this with:

```
$ ghc-pkg list containers
/home/dons/lib/ghc-7.0.3/package.conf.d
    containers-0.4.0.0
/home/dons/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.0.3/package.conf.d
    containers-0.3.0.0
```

while that by itself is fine, the problems occur when you have some of your libraries compiled against one version, and some against another. When those libraries in turn are brought together, e.g. by xmonad, you get type errors of this sort -- [the diamond dependency problem.](http://www.well-typed.com/blog/12)

A solution is to remove one of the versions of `containers`, and recompile any libs that then break, so you have a clean toolchain.

Comment: So I went through and trashed my entire package database and rebuild everything from scratch including finding a bug in the package dependancies of xmobar-0.13 when it tries to use libmpd-0.6 and I am pleased to announce that it now all works.

Answer (score 1):

You could also hide one of those packages with:

```
ghc-pkg hide containers-0.3.0.0
```